# Development Environment for RIDC in Java

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-ucm

I need to write code that communicates to Oracle Content Server 11g in Java.  My understanding is that it's done using RIDC (Remote Intradoc Client).

The best I can find on getting started is this:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e10807/c23_ridc.htm

However, it doesn't cover the development environment setup.  Where do I get the pieces to get started?  I'm assuming I need JDeveloper R1, is that correct?  Where do I download the SDK?  Thanks.

TD

Comment: What did they say on OTN?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install WebCenter Support API in JDeveloper. Search for the updates shown in the following image in Help->Check for Updates.

[image]

I am in PS6.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the Oracle WebCenter Portal extensions nor JDeveloper.

You can develop code using the RIDC library with any IDE, all you need is to make sure you have the correct version of the RIDC jar file on your classpath. You can obtain it from your Oracle_ECM1 installation home, in the /ucm/Distribution/RIDC folder.